# How to update a ko.computed with the value from an input box?

Tags: knockout.js

I am formatting the value of an input box which accepts date using `ko.computed` like this:

```
self.formatBillDate = ko.computed(function(){
        var billDate = self.basicData().billDate();
        return billDate[1]+"/"+billDate[2]+"/"+billDate[0];
    }
});
```

I understand I need to have read and write functions so that I can update the date. But I do not know how to do it exactly. I tried some code but I still getting the write error on a computed value. can somebody help?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and the errors you're getting with it

Comment: The documentation has a page on [writable computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) - have you seen that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you make computed variables writable by following the documentation on knockout site http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html

your code would be something similar to this, take a look at the jsfiddle I created for it https://jsfiddle.net/0wa1mkc9/ :

```
function viewModel(){
var self = this;
self.billDate = ko.observable("10/10/2015");    
self.formatBillDate = ko.computed(
    {
        read :function(){
            var d =new Date(self.billDate());
            return (d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+d.getDate()+"-"+d.getFullYear();
        },
        write:function(value){
            var d= new Date(value);
            self.billDate((d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+d.getDate()+"/"+d.getFullYear());
        },
        owner:self
    });
}
```

Comment: Sam it is right but my billDate fetching a value from back end and it already has a value. I just need to set it to a new value if the user writes something different in the input box. The bill date does not accept a parameter.

Comment: From your code I see that the billDate is a local variable, so instead of making that a local variable you can declare it as an observable much like I did in the script above ... and initialize it with self.basicData().billDate(). wouldn't that work?

Comment: Thank you Sam. I defined a new observable for billDate but it still does not work. I have a big observable (self.basicData) which contains a lot of data. One of them is 'bill' that has several properties incliding billDate. so I passing the self.basicData().billDate() to the ko.computed to format it. But I cannot change the value in the Write function. I cannot pass the new date to it ! I don't know maybe there is a method that allow me to set a new value for the self.basicData().billDate()! what do you think?

Comment: can't you do self.basicData().billDate(<value>)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use writable computed, e.g.:

```
self.formatBillDate = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        var billDate = self.basicData().billDate();
        return billDate[1]+"/"+billDate[2]+"/"+billDate[0];
    },
    write: function(newVal) {
        // some code to store new value in your variable
    }
});
```

#### Update 1

If you enter a bill date as a slash-delimited string, you can use something like:

```
self.formatBillDate = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        var billDate = self.basicData().billDate();
        return billDate[1]+"/"+billDate[2]+"/"+billDate[0];
    },
    write: function(newVal) {
        var values = newVal.split("/");
        self.basicData().billDate()[0] = values[2];
        self.basicData().billDate()[1] = values[0];
        self.basicData().billDate()[2] = values[1];
    }
});
```

If you enter a bill date as a DateTime, you can use something like:

```
self.formatBillDate = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        var billDate = self.basicData().billDate();
        return billDate[1]+"/"+billDate[2]+"/"+billDate[0];
    },
    write: function(newVal) {
        self.basicData().billDate()[0] = newVal.getFullYear();
        self.basicData().billDate()[1] = newVal.getDate();
        self.basicData().billDate()[2] = newVal.getMonth();
    }
});
```

It can be another code depends on date input control you are using to edit a bill date.

Comment: what if I want to keep the value in self.basicData().billDate() so that I can use it when the user hit the submit button to save the new information?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct that you need to include a `write` function for the computed observable. Here's what yours should look like:

```
self.formatBillDate = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var billDate = self.basicData().billDate();
        return billDate[1]+"/"+billDate[2]+"/"+billDate[0];
    },
    write: function (value) {
        var parts = value.split("/");
        self.basicData().billDate([ parts[2], parts[0], parts[1] ]);
    }
});
```